# The use of light gray type on this site makes it very difficult to read

Tags: feature-request, design

This website is very difficult to read. It appears you are using #444 for text color. Would you consider changing the default text color?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show where you're talking about?

Comment: I'm voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" since no specific example or screenshot of where this is happening has been provided. I sampled the colors on this page and the only font close to #444 (or RGB 68-68-68) is possibly the question title...